# How to send the firebaseConfig file to deploy on Vercel?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vercel

I created a project integrated with Firebase but I don't know how to send the private settings to deploy on Vercel.

I want to send these configurations to deploy on vercel:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

I tried using environment variables but they didn't work. I believe it was the way I configured it.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID
};
```

After leaving the firebaseConfig file like this, I configured the environment variables in Vercel by passing the real values.

[Environment Variables Vercel - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8C4d.jpg)

When I go to do something Firebase-related, I get this error on the console:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.8.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied: Consumer 'project:undefined' has been suspended.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: You should probably rewrite your question to focus on what how you tried while implementing [environment variables](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables) (which is the right thing to do here) that didn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to take your code and instructions and duplicate the behavior.

Comment: What does your configuration look like, not in the code?  What exactly isn't working the way you expect?  Is there an error message?  Something else specific? (You have to say more than ["it doesn't work"](https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#why-doesnt-it-work--what-am-i-missing-here) in order to get good help.)  We should be able to copy your code and instructions in order to reproduce the behavior you observe.